# Problemas ao usar o v-mask (Vue.JS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue.js-2

Queria usar uma mascara em alguns inputs componentizados, mas a mesma não funciona, segue os respectivos trechos de código: no main.js temos:

```
import VueMask from 'v-mask'
Vue.use(VueMask);
```

no meu componente, tenho:

```
<input class="form-control input floating-input"
 @input="$emit('input',$event.target.value)"
 :value="value"
 v-bind="$attrs" 
 :type="tipo"
 v-mask = mask
 :placeholder="placeholder" />
```

e nas props:

```
mask: {
    required: false,
    type: String
  }
```

e finalmente quando tento usar esse componente com a tal mascara:

```
<my-input tipo="text" placeholder=" " label="Telefone" 
  mask="(##) ####-####"
  v-model="empresa.phone"
  v-validate="'required'"
  data-vv-name='tel'>
</my-input>
```

Estranhamente não acontece nada, sem erros no console, a mascara apenas não é aplicada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está tentando usar a diretiva do `v-mask` mas está importando o plugin e não a diretiva.

Aqui está um exemplo funcionando:

main.js

```
import { VueMaskDirective } from "v-mask";
Vue.directive("mask", VueMaskDirective);
```

component.vue

```
<template>
  <input v-mask="mask" v-model="phone">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      mask: "(##) ####-####",
      phone: "4140028922"
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/olrkol8qk6

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Experimente assim caso o campo seja para Telefone ou Celular:

````
<template>
  <input v-mask="maskTel()" v-model="phone">
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      phone: "" // 4140028922 ou 41940028922
    };
  }, 
  methods: {
    maskTel() {
     if(!!phone) {
       return this.phone.length == 15 ? '(##) #####-####' : '(##) ####-#####'
     } else {
       return '(##) #####-####'
     }
  }
};
</script>
```
````